# How to fix NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, django

I am getting the error NoReverseMatch at / when I am trying to link my article to article detail page.

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'article-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

```
    {% for articles in object_list %}
    <div class="article">
        <div class="article-title">
            <a href="{% url 'article-detail' pk=article.pk %}"></a>
                <p class="p-title">{{ articles.title }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="article-content">
            <p>{{ articles.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

````
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='index'),

    path('article/create/', views.ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='article-create'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/update/', views.ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article-update'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo

Change this

```
<a href="{% url 'article-detail' pk=article.pk %}"></a>
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'article-detail' pk=articles.pk %}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
<a href="{% url 'article-detail' articles.pk %}"></a>
```

No need for `pk=` and you have a typo

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message, you'll find out that `reverse` was called with the empty string as 'pk' value, which means the template system could not resolve `article.pk` (=> either there was no context variable named 'article' or there was one but it didn't have a "pk" attribute or key or method). Then if you re-read your template code, you can see that you named your forloop iteration variable `articles` (plural), not `article` (singular), hence the error.

And the conclusions are 1/ that you should always carefully read the error message and 2/ that a good, sensible and **consistent** naming avoids a whole lot of typos...